# Unicode character into Java String or Integer

Tags: java

How to convert this char "��?'" into Java String or Integer. The expected value should be 28541.

We already tried below code but giving wrong value. The converted value is 16663.

```
public static Short unmarshallSignedCompFields(String compInput, int length) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    int packedSize = (length < 5) ? 2 : (length < 10) ? 4 : 8;

    byte[] recordByte = compInput.getBytes("Cp037");

    return MarshallExternalDecimalUtils.unmarshallShortFromBuffer(recordByte, 0, 

        packedSize, false, -1,

        MarshallExternalDecimalUtils.EXTERNAL_DECIMAL_SIGN_EBCDIC);

}
```

Comment: "How to convert this char "��?'" - That's already a String

Comment: I wonder if your post contained the actual character or actually the two diamond-question-marks and one question mark that you display.

Comment: BTW, the code you are showing is not your code. It is taken from [This blog](http://www.wmrichards.com/all-things-architecture/integrating-between-cobol.html). In addition to important information missing (the fact that you are trying to convert data from COBOL), you also always have to attribute work to the original author and give a link or a reference (if the work is not online). Otherwise it is considered plagiarism by the rules of StackOverflow.

Comment: Hi, the code was taken from this http://www.wmrichards.com/all-things-architecture and we are using the same approach when converting the BigDecimal into compressed data and Integer into binary(COMP) before sending to COBOL. These char "��?'" are taken from Data Studio which will be the input in JAVA after extraction from table. In Cobol it is showing as '...Ý' but from Data Studio it become different symbol when Java extract the data. We would like to know if possible to convert these ��?'  into readable character